# Table reference not compiling correctly

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I'm hoping for some guidance on why LaTeX isn't properly referencing this table.

```
\begin{table}[ht] 
\caption*{Table 2 \\ Number and Percentage}\label{tab:table2} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
\hline
 & \# & \# & \# & \% & \% \\ 
  \hline
  A  & 446 & 105 & 42 & 23.54 & 9.42 \\ 
  B  & 389 & 6 & 69 & 1.54 & 17.74 \\ 
  C  & 355 & 8 & 79 & 2.25 & 22.25 \\ 
  D  & 343 & 21 & 107 & 6.12 & 31.20 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

In Table~\ref{tab:table2} ...
```

I've tried compiling multiple times and moving the label inside the caption, but neither of those has worked; I still get "In Table ??" as output. Why might this be happening? Thanks for any help!

Comment: This works fine for me. Why are you manually captioning the table as "Table 2" inside of the `\caption`? This is what the command `\caption` is for; it automatically does these sorts of things. It might be helpful if you turn this into a **complete** [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), in case any packages that you might be loading are the culprit. Also, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Are you loading the `caption` package (*i.e.*, `\usepackage{caption}`)?

Comment: Yes to the caption package. It was the first (and so far only) way I found to put "Table 2:" and the name on two separate lines and to remove the colon. I just tried taking out and that solved the problem; is there a way I can keep that formatting, though? Thank you for the tips!

Comment: `\caption*` does not update a counter so does not set a referencable value. You need to use `\caption. But please _always_  post complete documents that reproduce the problem, not just fragments as here.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect what you're actually asking. Also, making this a complete MWE would be helpful, too. Anyway, I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 7):

As [@DavidCarlisle notes in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167123/table-reference-not-compiling-correctly/167127#comment384115_167123), `\caption*` does not update a counter, so there is nothing for `\label` to label.

The [`caption` documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) says (p. 17):

> The `longtable` package defines the command `\caption*` which typesets the caption *without label and without entry in the list of tables*. [. . .] The `caption` package offers this feature, too, so you can use this command now within every floating environment [emphasis added]

To achieve the format that you want ([as you noted in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167123/table-reference-not-compiling-correctly/167127#comment384114_167123)), you can just make use of `caption`'s `\captionsetup`.

<sup>Also, I've taken the liberty of using `booktabs` in the following MWE. You might want to use this package in order to typeset nicer tables. See the [documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for some tips on typesetting tables. In brief, the package provides `\toprule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\midrule`, which are nicer than `\hline`.</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=newline,
    justification=centering
    }

\usepackage{booktabs} % for nicer looking tables

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] 
\caption{Number and Percentage}\label{tab:table2} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
\toprule
 & \# & \# & \# & \% & \% \\ 
  \midrule
  A  & 446 & 105 & 42 & 23.54 & 9.42 \\ 
  B  & 389 & 6 & 69 & 1.54 & 17.74 \\ 
  C  & 355 & 8 & 79 & 2.25 & 22.25 \\ 
  D  & 343 & 21 & 107 & 6.12 & 31.20 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

In Table~\ref{tab:table2} ...

\end{document}
```

[image]